Is there any analytical expression for $\mathbf A\,\vdots\,\mathbf B$ as there is for $\mathbf A : \mathbf B=\mathrm{Tr}(\mathbf A\cdot\mathbf B)$?
We know the contraction product or double-dot product of two matrices is
$$\mathbf A:\mathbf B=A_{ij}B_{ji}=(A_{ij}B_{jk})_{i=k}=\mathrm{Tr}(\mathbf A\cdot\mathbf B)$$
The next case that might occur to us is
$$\mathbf A\,\vdots\,\mathbf B=A_{ijk}B_{kji}=\mathrm{Tr}(\mathbf A:\mathbf B)$$
where $\mathbf A$ and $\mathbf B$ are third order tensors. Did I do this right?
Another question arises: can this be generalized for any $n$th-dot product? If so, might it be
$$\mathbf A\,(\cdot)^n\,\mathbf B=A_{i_{n}\dots i_{1}}B_{i_{1}\dots i_{n}}=\mathrm{Tr}(\mathbf A(\cdot)^{n-1}\mathbf B)\;?$$
Also, can this last expression be written in terms of single dot products/matrix products?

The reason this works is because trace of a matrix $A_{ij}$ is just a contraction $A_{ii}$. This is just a matter of notation, you can write whatever you want, though this "dot-product-esque" notation is something I don't like because it doesn't make it clear which "slots"/indices of the tensors you are contracting with which.
With that caveat, the notation you've presented is reasonable and sensible.

Thank you Nicholas for your eplanaion and confirmaion. Is there a name associated to these products? Is there any reference on these?

@HugdeRoda I think the term you're looking for is tensor contraction, but if you mean specifically the $A_{ijk}B_{jki}$ sort of form then no, I don't think you will find any reference, it's too specific and you don't gain anything over just studying contractions.
